# compile issue with jigsaw http server on linux

Tags: java, makefile

I'm working on Jigsaw http server.I downloaded zip file on jigsaw offical page and I modified java files in the src folder. Every folder has a `Makefile`. So I went to the principal folder and in the terminal I execute `make` command and appear...

```
building  org.w3c
building  org.w3c.cvs
building  org.w3c.jigsaw
building  org.w3c.jigsaw.acl
building  org.w3c.jigsaw.auth
building  org.w3c.jigsaw.admin
```

In this way It compiled or not?

```
PACKAGE="org"

JIGSAWPACKAGES = \
    w3c

PACKAGES = $(JIGSAWPACKAGES)

TOP=../..
include $(TOP)/makefiles/package.make

jigsawdoc::
    rm -rf ../../../Doc/Programmer/api/*
    javadoc -J-ms32m -J-mx64m -d ../../../Doc/Programmer/api/ \
        `make -s dumpjigsawpackages`
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it did compile. Check for binaries.

Comment: Unfortunately for an strange and unreasonable reason the effects of my own modify aren't applied

Comment: oh no! could you attach the makefile?

Comment: I attached the makefile principal but it is more convenient you get from jigsaw site zip file.